# What are the steps involved in this for loop to reach the result that it prints?

Tags: c

I understand what the following code prints but I dont understand how? I know we have the outer for loop, as i is less than 3, then it moves to the next loop. I'm so confused I can't even explain what I dont understand about it.

I would really appreciate someone explaining it in steps. Its from a computer science intro tutorial. Maybe this is not for me

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int i, j;

  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      printf("#");
    }
    printf("#");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

tried running it and got ### ### ###, i just dont understand how?

Comment: C and C++ are different languages.  This looks like C so I'm removing the C++ tag.

Comment: It's just going to print `#########` with no trailing newline.  There are no spaces in the output, since neither of the two `printf` calls prints a space.  In any case, you have a simple nested loop.  Loops can contain statements, including other loops.  If having both loops in the same function confuses you, think of moving the inner loop to a function, then calling that function from inside the outer loop.  It should behave the same.

Comment: *I would really appreciate someone explaining it in steps* -- The problem with this question is that it is open-ended -- we have no idea what you know or don't know.   Simple coding logic like this is best taught in a good C book.

Comment: Learn to use the debugger. You can use it to step through the code line by line, inspecting the value of variables and seeing what is happening on each line. If you don't know how to use the debugger, now is an excellent time to start learning, as the code that you've posted is pretty simple and would be easy to observe in the debugger. SO is not a tutorial site. It's a site for **specific questions** about an actual problem you're having with code, and *Please tutor me step by step on how this code works* is not a specific question.

Comment: “tried running it and got ### ### ###”.  Then the posted code is most certainly not what you ran.  The posted code prints 12 hashes, no white space and no newline.  Perhaps either the tutorial has a mis-print, or the code has been copied incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

Think through the code sequentially and run it "in your head".

When we enter the outer loop, we set `i` to `0`.

We enter the inner loop.
We set `j` to `0`.  `0` is less than `3` so we execute the block of code in the loop.
We print `#`.
We set `j` to `1`.  `1` is less than `3` so we execute again.
We print `#`.
We set `j` to `2`.   `2` is less than `3` so we execute again.
We print `#`.
We set `j` to `3`.  `3` is *not* less than `3` so the inner loop ends.

The outer loop prints `#`.

We set `i` to `1`.  `1` is les than 3 so the outer loop executes a second time.

The inner loop doesn't care about `i` so the behavior is exactly the same.  `j` starts at `0` and is incremented 3 times; 3 `#`s are printed.

The outer loop prints `#`.

We set `i` to `2`.  Still less than three, so the outer loop executes a third time.

The inner loop execute 3 times like before.  3 more `#`s are printed.

The outer loop prints `#`.

We set `i` to `3`.  Now `i` is *not* less than 3 so the outer loop ends.

We `return` from `main` and the program ends.

Note that the *actual* output is `############`; twelve `#` characters and no newline.